# Make angular provider written in typescript minification safe

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have written an angular provider that needs $injector service to be injected in the $get function but I do not know how to write this in typescript and make it minification safe. Something like
    static $injector = [''];
notation that works for services and controllers.

Typescript:

```
export class ApiProvider implements IApiProvider {
    private baseRoute: string = '';
    private endpoints: { [name: string]: IApiEndPointConfig };

    static $inject = ['$injector']; //THIS DOES NOT WORK FOR PROVIDERS
    constructor() {
        this.baseRoute = '';
        this.endpoints = {};
    }

            // MORE CODE

    $get = ($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService): { [name: string]: ApiEndpoint } => {
        var api: { [name: string]: ApiEndpoint } = {};
        var self:ApiProvider = this;
        angular.forEach(this.endpoints, (endpointConfig, name) => {
            api[name] = $injector.instantiate(ApiEndpoint, {
                baseRoute: self.baseRoute,
                endpointConfig: endpointConfig
            });
        });

        return api;
    };
}
```

The generated javascript for the $get function is:

```
this.$get = function ($injector) {
    var api = {};
    var self = _this;
    angular.forEach(_this.endpoints, function (endpointConfig, name) {
        api[name] = $injector.instantiate(Model.ApiEndpoint, {
            baseRoute: self.baseRoute,
            endpointConfig: endpointConfig
        });
    });

    return api;
};
```

And what I want it to be is something like:

```
this.$get = ['$injector', function ($injector) {
    var api = {};
    var self = _this;
    angular.forEach(_this.endpoints, function (endpointConfig, name) {
        api[name] = $injector.instantiate(Model.ApiEndpoint, {
            baseRoute: self.baseRoute,
            endpointConfig: endpointConfig
        });
    });

    return api;
}];
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think I got it. After reading the $injector documentation more closely I found that the $inject string array notation can be used on any function. Thus I did something like:

```
constructor(){
   this.$get.$inject = ['$injector'];
}

$get = ($injector: ng.auto.IInjectorService): { [name: string]: ApiEndpoint } => {
    //using $injector
};
```

which produces:

```
this.$get = function ($injector) {
   //using $injector                    
};

this.$get.$inject = ['$injector'];
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct way to do this and the reason why https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L11-L14 exists in the definition ;)

Comment: Great find @basarat. I will have to start looking in the def files more.

Comment: I actually added that https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/commit/6fc8cd92ed8205eed61945ba875fa7fe8169073c ;)

Comment: Talk about access to the "source". Your Typescript+Angular contributions are much appreciated (I've seen you answer almost all related questions in SO). Nice typescript videos on youtube also.

Comment: it's so funny, when you see what you did here, it's like, duh, of course that's how you should do it